# Firefox extension - Invalid valid manifest

Tags: firefox-addon, manifest

I'm trying to port my Chrome extension to Firefox but i'm not able to make it work.
The validator says it's okay:
[image]
(https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator)

(Sorry for spanish language, but firefox doesn't give the option to switch their website language.
It says that there are 0 errors and 611 warnings [just evals-Vue.js..])

But browser fails to execute it:
[image]

Since it doesn't display any useful debugging information i can't fix the bug.

I've also tried to open this support request in their forums, but like their browser, it doesn't work too:

[image]

Gets stuck on that step.

The app works fine in Chrome (it's already in the store)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Without even a link to where we can download the file you are attempting to install, there is absolutely no way for us to be able to determine the actual problem. It would be nice to have something so we can duplicate the issue. Even if the issue is exactly what you have answered, being able to duplicate the issue would allow us to provide feedback to Mozilla to make the error messages you see more descriptive of the problem, which would make life easier for other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox error says `does not contain a valid install manifest` but the real error is that the compressed file was .zip rather than .xpi

Comment: In my case I zipped the folder and not the files directly.